# Is this my hostname and DNS domain name?

Tags: dns, hostname

I am trying to find what my VM's hostname is. When I do `cat /etc/hosts` I get:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Is `localhost` the hostname? The DNS domain name isn't written where do I find that? When I write `hostname -d` I get `hostname: Name or service not known`

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is a local hostname used to communicate on loopback. It's like 127.0.0.1.

Your DNS hostname is trickier to find. First, you don't have one per se. You have to configure one in your dns server, then you'll be able to ping your hostname.

The Command hostname, without the "-d" will print your VM's hostname. At least the one you configured. For me, without any configuration it is "localhost.localdomain". You should have the same.

What are you trying to achieve with your hostname?

Answer (score 0):

No, localhost is (most likely) not your hostname. To find out your hostname use the command

```
hostname
```

and use

```
hostname -f
```

to display the fully qualified domain name (FQDN). How the hostname and the DNS domain are set depends on the distribution, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313219/64248) for more on this.