# Change hostname for systemd on Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, systemd, hostname

I swapped-in a new motherboard, cpu, and renamed a machine. The old machine name was `bulldozer`, and the new mchine name is `skylake`. I used [`hostnamectrl --static`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html) according to [How to permanently change hostname in Fedora 21](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162393) since the machine is Fedora 25.

When the machine boots, `systemd` is still using the old name:

```
skylake:~$ sudo dmesg | grep bulldozer
[    1.085387] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <bulldozer>.
skylake:~$ hostname
skylake
```

According to the [`honamectrl` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html), it sounds like `--static` is supposed to do it: *"... the static hostname which is used to initialize the kernel hostname at boot ..."*.

Grepping `/etc` does not reveal any hits for the old name:

```
skylake:~$ sudo grep -R bulldozer /etc/ 2>/dev/null
skylake:~$
```

I also tried `/sbin/sysctl -q -w kernel.hostname=skylake` according to [Correctly setting the hostname - Fedora 20 on Amazon EC2](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37413/correctly-setting-the-hostname-fedora-20-on-amazon-ec2/). But it did not work, either.

How do I change the host name for `systemd`?

Comment: Please demonstrate that the `/etc/hostname`, and indeed the `/etc` and `/` filesystems, that you are looking at with `grep` are the same ones that process #1 running `systemd` saw before any filesystems were mounted, bind mounts were made, roots were changed, and so forth.

Comment: @JdeBP - Certainly. How would you like me to do it? Or how does one provide the information?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](https://fedoramagazine.org/set-hostname-fedora/), you should run `hostnamectl set-hostname name` where `name` is your desired hostname. I presume you should run this as root.

Comment: Thanks, but no joy. Its amazing how far we've come since the original `hostname` command. The original command worked great for years. After all the improvements, we can no longer set the hostname. Classic over engineering by a bunch of programmers...

Comment: It is ironic that the other answer here actually demonstrates what they are engineering this _for_.  It's the how-to-do-this-by-writing-the-file approach, in a way that attempts to allow this to be done by an unprivileged user.  It makes a common mistake in the use of `sudo` and does not in fact work.  The `hostnamed`/`hostnamectl` system is engineered so that both unprivileged and privileged users run the same command, with `hostnamed` consulting the "policy kit" mechanism for authorization checks.  So M. Leuenhagen's presumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful answer, but its provided for completeness. The kernel was updated today. The old Fedora kernel was `4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64`. The new kernel is `4.9.13-201.fc25.x86_64`.

After the kernel updates, I manually delete the old kernel from `/boot` using `rm`. This is a standard procedure for me on Linux (I always perform it to remove unwanted cruft). In this case, I ran:

```
su -
cd /boot
rm -rf *4.9.13-200*
rm -rf .*4.9.13-200*
```

After manual removal, I regenerate the Grub menu and then reboot. This is also a standard procedure for me on Linux.

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

After the reboot, the old name was no longer present:

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i '(bulldozer|skylake)'
[  0.065941] Performance Events: PEBS fmt3+, Skylake events, 32-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[  1.096957] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <skylake>.
```

So, something affected the hostname used by systemd, but I am not sure what it was.

I tried regenerating `grub.cfg` previously, so I'm not convinced its the answer. I'm guessing a package triggered the correction, and after the reboot I observed things were as expected.

Answer (score -2):

This method is deprecated in current version of systemd, but I'm keeping it here as reference for some of the comments.

> The quickest way would be `sudo echo -e "bulldozer" > /etc/hostname`
>   followed by a reboot.
>
> Systemd's network stack should pick it up and apply it on startup.
>
> You can also use a text editor and create/edit `/etc/hostname`
>   manually. (I recommend `nano`, but you need to install it manually on
>   fedora first)

Systemd's `hostnamectl` is supposed to be the way to do it today, it seems.

Comment: `cat /etc/hostname` shows the expected name.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work (or it never worked for me with `systemd`).

Comment: @Jakuje on Arch Linux, which uses `systemd`, modifying `/etc/hostname` *does* successfully change the hostname.